# Spring boot and JPA override mapped entity name/id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a couple of entities mixed with Embedded attributes. I've been able to override embedded column names using `@AttributeOverrides` and `@AttributeOverride` but it doesn't seem to work for nested entities.

see below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride( name = "streeNumber", column = @Column(name = "branch_street_number")),
            @AttributeOverride( name = "streetName", column = @Column(name = "branch_street_name")),
            @AttributeOverride( name = "lga", column = @Column(name = "branch_lga_id")),
            @AttributeOverride( name = "city", column = @Column(name = "branch_city"))
    })
    private Location location;
```

Location entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class Location {
    private String streetNumber;
    private String streetName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private LocalGovernmentArea lga;
    private String city;
```

the lga column still generates as `lga_id` instead of `branch_lga_id`

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I can override the entity name using `@AssociationOverrides`

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride( name = "streetNumber", column = @Column(name = "branch_street_number")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "streetName", column = @Column(name = "branch_street_name")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "lga", column = @Column(name = "branch_lga_id")),
        @AttributeOverride( name = "city", column = @Column(name = "branch_city"))
})
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(
                name = "lga", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "branch_lga_id"))
})
private Location location;
```

That does the trick!